# Ubuntu 13.04 Lamp and drush

Tags: ubuntu, drupal, drupal-7, lamp, drush

I'm running Lamp stack on Ubuntu 13.04, and when I try to use drush to, for example, cache-clear, I get the following error :[image]

I know it's because of Lamp. For example when I want to connect to mysql, I have to manually specify the socket file, which is fine (thanks to aliases). But how can I specify socket for drush? Has anyone found a solution to this apart from removing lamp and installing proper stack?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the db host in settings.php to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?